# Mirror API database access issue

Tags: php, sqlite, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I just installed the Google mirror API. I have everything setup except after I log in to the API, I get this error message:

```
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in     C:\xampp\htdocs\mirror-client.php on line 33

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open database: unable to open database file' in C:\xampp\htdocs\util.php:62 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\util.php(62): SQLite3->__construct('/tmp/database.s...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\util.php(26): init_db() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\oauth2callback.php(41): store_credentials('107736579479351...', '{"access_token"...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\util.php on line 62
```

It seems that the API can't create the database or do I need to create it?

I tried making a folder and database as it is set up in the config.php file "tmp/database.sqlite" but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Im facing same problem, did you have your solution on this>

Comment: It seems he found the solution and answered his own questions, but didn't mark his own answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that you had to make your own database for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

It can mean that the directory/folder you placed the sqlite file in (and the file itself) does not have the correct permissions. You need to make sure both the folder and the file have read and write permissions. The xampp directory in my environment has read/write permissions. You might want to place your database there, at least for testing purposes.

Note: The /tmp directory as mentioned in "/tmp/database.sqlite" is a Linux/Mac directory. You may want to change the value of *$sqlite_database* in the *config.php* file to point to a file in a Windows directory.